# How to add annotation to certain entity functions, while generating through hibernate

Tags: hibernate, annotations

I am generating entity classes through hibernate using eclipse for a database table.

The table has an id column. I want to add custom annotation(myprojectannotation) like mentioned in example for generated set function for ID.

```
@myprojectannotation(field="id")
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to use your own annotation with full functionality like @Column annotation? If so, you'll be bogged into all Hibernate AOP stuff. I don't advice you to do that